# Right shift for signed integer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num;

  printf("enter the number\n");
  scanf("%d",&num);

  int a,b;
  printf("enter the number of bits yiu want to shift\n");
  scanf("%d",&b);

  a=num>>b;

  printf("a is=%d\n",a);

  return 0;
}
```

Here for positive values of num, i get expected result.But with the negative values of num can,t find the answer giving a dry run of my programm.
Just example consider i give num=-1
So -1 will be represented as 1111111111111111 and right shifting it by 1 should produce output 0111111111111111 that is 32767 in decimal form.But the output is -1.

Comment: By definition, right shift of a `signed` integer "drags" the value of the sign-bit to the right!

Comment: @barakmanos using that definition i am expecting the output to be 32767.

Comment: And by the way, those values in your example (16 ones, 32767, etc) are correct only if `sizeof(int) == 2`. Have you verified that this is indeed the case on your platform (compiler)? Because I sincerely doubt that it is.

Comment: "using that definition i am expecting 32767"??? I am reading in your question `should produce output 0111111111111111`, which proves that either you don't understand this definition or... well, that's about it really...

Comment: @barakmanos: What definition are you referring to? The C standard doesn't say that; it says the result is implementation-defined (see R Sahu's answer; he beat me to it).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oh... that's good to know, thanks for pointing that out (BTW, have you ever worked on a platform which implements it in a different manner?).

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't know. If I need to use shift operators, I try to apply them only to unsigned types.

Comment: @barakmanos Example sidebar: Even thought the old machine was passing out of use, the data checksum it generated depended on the old machine's non-2's complement shifts and signed zeros.  So to continue checking and generating the same check code - as data formats live on - my 2's complement machine needed to emulate sign-magnitude integer math to get the right check code.  Now had _that_ machine not used UB, it would not be a modern issue.

Comment: @KeithThompson: We mostly apply shift only on `unsigned` operands anyway (due to the typical nature of the tasks that require shifting, such as bit-masking, etc)... But it nevertheless kinda makes me wonder about all those cases where I've applied right-shift on `signed` operands with a deliberate intention of "dragging" that sign-bit...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the C99 standard N1256 (emphasis mine):

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>
> 5 The result of **E1** `>>` **E2** is **E1** right-shifted **E2** bit positions. If **E1** has an unsigned type or if **E1** has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of **E1 X 2<sup>E2</sup>**. *If **E1** has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined*.

Comment: And, just for completeness, this is the same in C89 and C11.

Comment: Basically, if you want a 0 to be shifted in, cast to an unsigned integer, shift, then cast back to a signed.

Comment: So i can not predict the value of shift operators on signed numbers?

Comment: @user2738777, not in a platform independent way. There is no guarantee that the behavior will be same when you switch from `gcc` to `Visual Studio`.

Comment: @user2738777 As R Sahu said, not in a platform independent way. Some platforms may shift in the sign bit (as yours did), but some may shift in a 0. You never know

Answer (score 6):

The behavior of right-shifting a negative value is implementation defined in C.

For `gcc`, from the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html), the sign-bit is propagated (emphasis mine):

> (4.5 Integers) *The results of some bitwise operations on signed integers (C90 6.3, C99 and C11 6.5)*
>
> Bitwise operators act on the representation of the value including both the sign and value bits, where the sign bit is considered immediately above the highest-value value bit. **Signed ‘>>’ acts on negative numbers by sign extension**.

On other implementation, some small embedded platforms don't propagate the sign-bit but most implementations do propagate it.